# Android SntpClient request always false

Tags: android, ntp

I am trying to use SntpClient.java to get NTP date and show it in a textView

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    tVNTP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoNTP);
    tVNTP.setText("Waiting ntp server response...");
    consultaNTP();
}
```

So this is my onCreate(), where I call a function which is:

```
public void consultaNTP(){
    SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
    if (client.requestTime("es.pool.ntp.org", 30000)) {
        long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - client.getNtpTimeReference();
        Log.i("consultarNTP", "Value: >"+now+"<");
        tVNTP.setText("Value: >"+now+"<");
    }
    else{
        Log.i("consultaNTP","ERROR: Request unsuccessful");
        tVNTP.setText("ERROR: Request unsuccessful");
    }
}
```

Moreover I have the next permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

What happens is that I have no exception but

```
client.requestTime("es.pool.ntp.org", 30000)
```

is always returning false. Do you have any hint to make it work? The examples I have seen are not different from mine but this is not working at the moment...

Solution:

```
public void consultaNTP(){
    final SntpClient client = new SntpClient();

    new Thread()
    {
        public void run() {
            if (client.requestTime("es.pool.ntp.org", 30000)) {
                long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - client.getNtpTimeReference();
                Log.i("consultarNTP", "Value: >"+now+"<");
                //tVNTP.setText("Value: >"+now+"<");
            }
            else{
                Log.i("consultaNTP","ERROR: Request unsuccessful");
                //tVNTP.setText("ERROR: Request unsuccessful");
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Make your network calls in seprate thread ;) Your code should provide an exception in catlog that says something like "No network on MainThread".

Comment: you are right! thanks!

Comment: Standard error ;) Is aksed a 1000 times a day here.